Trying to add a phone number to verified destination numbers in AWS End User Messaging results in error 400
I can't send text messages to my phone number (I'm trying to add my phone number to the verified destination numbers in AWS End User Messaging) or simulator phone numbers. Every action results in:
Access Denied - MoreInformation="https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sms-voice/latest/userguide/awssupport-spend-threshold.html" RequestId: 4ad02264-2662-4de9-bd5f-f97e93807268 HttpStatusCode: 400

My spending limit is $1. I spent $0. This is a new AWS account.
My main problem is to enable users to register with Amazon Cognito using their phone numbers (and verify them). I don't care about registering the actual users. For now, I'd like to test this functionality only with my phone number or log the messages somehow.
How to fix this problem?
